# Error: BrokenCount>0 After I installed ROS(Robot Operating System) indigo

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Like everyone who had this problem did There is a warning sign and it says   "the error message was 'BrokenCount > 0',this usually means that you installed packages that have unmet dependencies."

And when I try to install something like vim.I get this

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-rosdep : Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.4.0) but it is not   going    to be installedvim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1) but 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After I tried `sudo apt-get -f install` The terminal shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   python-rosdistro python-rosdistro-modules
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   python-rosdistro python-rosdistro-modules
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 389 not upgraded.
139 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/37.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 295 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-  modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How could I solve this problem? Thanks for your time and hope to get advice.

Answer (score 1):

It is reported in https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/19481.

You need to install `dpkg` `1.17.5ubuntu5.8` by `sudo apt-get install dpkg -y`.